# Which ML to use for search suggestion?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, reinforcement-learning

## Problem:

---

I want to create a program to organize text information and fast access to relevant documents. I would like to train a ML model to analyse the current situation and to suggest the next action.
The Workflow should look like this:

- Model gets document type and document text.(Let's say its a Bill from Mr. M. Learning)
- Then the model should suggest based on previous actions what the user wants to do next (e.g the user opened this bill and was coming from the unpaid bills tab of the application)
- In this case the model should suggest to send a reminder to M. Learning or open his previous bills etc.

I hope the problem I would like to solve is clear. The goal would be to have a network for every document which knows where to go next based on previous actions.

I thought of using reinforcement learning and reward the model if a user actually uses a suggested action. Maybe combining it with natural language processing for document analysis?

## Question:

---

I would like the model to continue to collect usage data from the user and continue **unsupervised** learning.

Is this the way to go or are there models that are more suitable for my purpose? Any advice is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At first sight, the text analysis part and the 'suggested action' part are distinct, with the latter possibly depending on the former. In general I'd say that it's quite ambitious, if only because it's probably not simple to design all the possible actions. The model won't be able to discover new types of actions during the unsupervised part, of course.

Comment: You're definitely right. The advantage is that it's totally fine if the model is off because the users would then take desired action by themselves. But how could I use this information to train the model again?

Comment: Potentially this is possible, but it depends if the new action can be represented with in the predefined space of possible actions. It also requires either the user to enter the new possible action themselves in the system, or the the system to be able to capture the action automatically. The latter would limit possible actions to the ones that can be captured by the software.

Comment: Perfect, the scope of possible actions is limited by the software. The software has a pool of actions from which the user can choose. There is no way that a user defines a new action. Let's say for example there are 10 basic actions. (New File, delete file,move file, write an email etc) The model just should predict when the user would possibly use an actions based on usage data. Is reinforcement learning the right way to go?

Comment: I don't know much about reinforcement learning, sorry.